How to handle JavaScript in the InAppWebView flutter and how to pass the data from webView to flutter?
I need to receive data in the web_view in flutter from webView. how to possible it? How can I manage the JavaScript in flutter's InAppWebView?

First you should listen the js callback in the onLoadStart.
InAppWebViewController? webViewController;


InAppWebView(
      onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
        webViewController = controller;
      },
      onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
        controller.addJavaScriptHandler(
            handlerName: "FlutterCallback",
            callback: (args) {
              String jsonFromWeb = args[0];
              print(jsonFromWeb);
            });
      },
      initialSettings: InAppWebViewSettings(
        javaScriptEnabled: true,
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
        cacheEnabled: true,
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
   ),
);

and in the website side you send the data like this,
var isAppReady = false;

window.addEventListener("flutterInAppWebViewPlatformReady", function (event) {
    isAppReady = true;
});

if (isAppReady) {
    window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('FlutterCallback', jsonDataToFlutter);
}

